# In Angular, if I import a shared module but only need 1 thing from it, won't that be a unnecessarily huge import?

Tags: angular

Let's say I have a **SharedModule** which imports a bunch of services, pipes and so on, and then in **FeatureModuleA** I want to use ONE of the pipes declared in SharedModule.

Then I'm importing SharedModule, which might contain 100 different pipes but 99 of them become unused and dead code in FeatureModuleA. Isn't this very ineffecient?

This made me think of tree shaking, where webpack might remove unused code, but AFAIK, tree shaking removes code that has been exported but not yet imported. In my case everything IS imported by SharedModule, so exactly how will this work? Will I have 99% unused code just because I needed 1/100 pipes?

Anyone care to shed some light on this? Couldn't find any info in the official docs.

Comment: Is the shared module presents in your APpModule?

Comment: No I thought I only import the SharedModule in those feature modules that requires something from SharedModule.

Comment: If your sharedmodule has been imported in AppModule, you can mention pipes in providers. So that you can access it anywhere in components

Comment: You can also add a private module to your `componentA` and simply add in it the few pipe/services you need

Answer (score 5):

If your application is growing and you need to import a specific service/pipe/model. You can try implementing an **index barrel** in every module you create

> Example, this is your **/shared** directory structure. Consider creating an **index.ts** exporting all the files under /shared directory.

```
 /shared
      /services
          user.service.ts
          tenant.service.ts
      /pipes
          table.pipe.ts
      /models
          admin.model.ts
          product.model.ts
 index.ts                       --> Your index.ts
 shared.module.ts
```

> After creating an **index.ts**, supply all the exports under the shared directory:

```
export * from './services/user.service';
export * from './services/tenant.service';

export * from './table.pipe';

export * from './models/admin.model';
export * from './product.model';
```

*You can also use this when importing it on your shared module to avoid a long list of imports and promote a one-line style of import*

*Example:*
**import { UserService, TenantService, TablePipe, Admin, Product } from './index.ts'**

> So when you want to import just one 1 service/pipe/model to your other modules example **UserModule** just call the **index barrel**

```
import { UserService } from '../shared/index';

// or if you want to import 2 items e.g a service and a pipe
import { UserService, TablePipe } from '../shared/index';


@NgModule({
   declarations: [`...`],
   imports: [`...`],
   providers: [ UserService ]    --> imported from /shared index barrel
})
export class UserModule {}
```

*This way whenever your application is growing so as the shared module you can just call them through index barrel one by one or a combination of 2 or more items*

Comment: Interesting. But doesn't this barrel file method make the SharedModule obsolete? Why not just import this way in ALL my modules? It will be rare that one feature module will need EVERYTHING declared in SharedModule...

Comment: No, SharedModule would not become obsolete as barrels are only there to shorten your imports to one-line declaration which will then be utilized by ur own shared module & other modules. So in your case if you only want the TablePipe from /shared directory - no need to import the SharedModule but instead import only TablePipe which can easily be access "import { TablePipe } from './shared/index'" instead of supplying its complete directory address then include it on the module of your choice.

Comment: This is also a good to read resource from Medium Site - It also talks about shared and feature modules - Hope this will help also:
https://medium.com/@tomastrajan/6-best-practices-pro-tips-for-angular-cli-better-developer-experience-7b328bc9db81

Comment: Hey guys. 
One doubt... Once I have an index.ts based on "barrel concept" inside my shared module, what do I do with shared.module.ts file?
Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi @RogérioOliveira, i don't if i got it right but the index.ts full of exports will be used inside the shared module to import all of the required files in one line just like how angular implemented it's imports. The SharedModule is a module needed to be imported inside the other modules to share those shared imports that can be utilized thereafter. Hope this answers your question :)

Comment: Thanks @KShewengger well I started with Angular recently, so don't mind my ignorance... I use this concept a lot in my Vue and React apps (wonderful). Actually, I'm studying all the concepts about Angular's modules. Specifically about shared module, I'm trying to find out some way to break it down in "local shared modules" instead of a global one. My app has some modules that are imported just by few modules. This way instead of putting these guys inside my global shared module, I'd like to have a local shared module where I can import and export just these specific modules. Thank you so much.

Comment: That's great! No problem :)

Answer (score 3):

Importing a full module such as the `SharedModule` is inefficient since it contains other components as well.

If you are planning to use these pipes elsewhere as well, what you can do is to create a common module(maybe even inside the `SharedModule`) that contains all the pipes. In that case you will only be importing the necessary pipes.

If you are planning to scale up the application a lot, this might even help you with avoiding circular dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I will answer this since from what I read on the docs, the answers don't take into account that Angular only evaluates the Modules imported just the first time, so for example, having a `sharedModule.ts` with all your shared modules, is a good practice and does not mean your bundle will be bigger at all.

From the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq):

> **What if I import the same module twice?**
>
> That's not a problem. When
>   three modules all import Module 'A', Angular evaluates Module 'A'
>   once, the first time it encounters it, and doesn't do so again.
>
> That's true at whatever level A appears in a hierarchy of imported
>   NgModules. When Module 'B' imports Module 'A', Module 'C' imports 'B',
>   and Module 'D' imports [C, B, A], then 'D' triggers the evaluation of
>   'C', which triggers the evaluation of 'B', which evaluates 'A'. When
>   Angular gets to the 'B' and 'A' in 'D', they're already cached and
>   ready to go.
>
> Angular doesn't like NgModules with circular references, so don't let
>   Module 'A' import Module 'B', which imports Module 'A'.

Here are the DOES and DONTS of your shared module: ([Read the article](https://medium.com/dev-jam/5-tips-best-practices-to-organize-your-angular-project-e900db08702e))

- DO declare components, pipes, directives, and export them.
- DO import FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule and other (3rd-party) modules you
  need.
- DO import the SharedModule into any other Feature Modules.
- DO NOT provide app-wide singleton services in your SharedModule. Instead move these to the CoreModule.
- DO NOT import the SharedModule into the AppModule.